# Unable to call the function from the mocked component class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a junit test method as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class StoreIdAssignmentServiceTest {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(StoreIdAssignmentServiceTest.class);

    @InjectMocks
    private StoreIdAssignmentService storeIdAssignmentService;

    @Mock
    private StoreIdAssignmentFactory storeIdAssignmentFactory;

    @Mock
    private DatabaseService databaseService;
    @Test
    public void rollUpFeed_Single_DealerAndStoreID_NoExisting() {
        List<ScmsaPosTransRollup> scmsaPosTransRollupFeedList = new ArrayList<>();
        ScmsaPosTransRollup posTransRollup = new ScmsaPosTransRollup();
        posTransRollup.setJobLogId(8269726L);
        posTransRollup.setDealerCode("3119255");
        posTransRollup.setStoreId("9842");
        posTransRollup.setTransactionDate(Timestamp
                .valueOf("2018-03-01 13:00:00.00"));
        posTransRollup.setQuantity(4);
        posTransRollup.setRollupType("H");
        scmsaPosTransRollupFeedList.add(posTransRollup);
        Mockito.when(
                databaseService.getUnProcessedRollUpFeedBasedonRollupType("H"))
                .thenReturn(scmsaPosTransRollupFeedList);
        List<PosHourlySt> existingPosHourlyStEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        Mockito.when(databaseService.getDealerCodeFromPosHourly("3119255"))
                .thenReturn(existingPosHourlyStEntries);

        Mockito.when(databaseService.getDealerCodeFromPosHourly("3119255"))
                .thenReturn(existingPosHourlyStEntries);
        storeIdAssignmentService.processHourlyStateFeed();
        assertNotNull(posHourlyStRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

And My StoreIdAssignmentService  class will be:

```
@Service
public class StoreIdAssignmentService {

private StoreIdAssignmentFactory storeIdAssignmentFactory;
    private DatabaseService databaseService;

    @Autowired
    public StoreIdAssignmentService(StoreIdAssignmentFactory storeIdAssignmentFactory,
            DatabaseService databaseService) {
        this.storeIdAssignmentFactory = storeIdAssignmentFactory;
        this.databaseService = databaseService;
    }

    public void processHourlyStateFeed() {
    .......................

                calculateStateForPosHourlyStTransaction(posHourlyStToConsider, newPosHourlyStEntries);
                .........
            }

            List<ScmsaPosTransRollup> scmsaPosTransRollupUpdatedFlagList = storeIdAssignmentFactory
                    .createUpdatedRollUpEntries(rollUpFeedByDealerCode);

            saveAndUpdatePosHourlyStAndRollUpEntries(newPosHourlyStEntries, existingPosHourlyStEntries,
                    rollUpFeedByDealerCode, scmsaPosTransRollupUpdatedFlagList);
        }
    }


    private Map<String, List<ScmsaPosTransRollup>> groupDealerCodeRollUpFeedByStoreId(
            List<ScmsaPosTransRollup> rollUpFeedByDealerCode) {

        // Grouping the rollUpFeedByDealerCode by storeID
        return rollUpFeedByDealerCode.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ScmsaPosTransRollup::getStoreId));

    }

    private void calculateStateForPosHourlyStTransaction(ScmsaPosTransRollup scmsaPosTransRollupToConsider, List<PosHourlySt> newPosHourlyStEntries) {

        List<PosHourlySt> posHourlyStList = newPosHourlyStEntries.stream().filter(
                hourlyState -> (hourlyState.getStartDate().before(scmsaPosTransRollupToConsider.getTransactionDate())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

                ..............

            PosHourlySt posHourlySt=storeIdAssignmentFactory.createHourlyStEntryFromRollUp(scmsaPosTransRollupToConsider,
                    Timestamp.valueOf(scmsaPosTransRollupToConsider.getTransactionDate().toLocalDateTime().withHour(0).withMinute(0)),
                    Timestamp.valueOf(scmsaPosTransRollupToConsider.getTransactionDate().toLocalDateTime().withHour(23).withMinute(59)));
            newPosHourlyStEntries.add(posHourlySt);

            ....................

    }
}
```

and My Factory class would be:

```
@Component
public class StoreIdAssignmentFactory {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StoreIdAssignmentFactory.class);

    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    public StoreIdAssignmentFactory(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    public PosHourlySt createHourlyStEntryFromRollUp(ScmsaPosTransRollup scmsaPosTransRollup, Timestamp startDate, Timestamp endDate){
        PosHourlySt posHourlySt = new PosHourlySt();
        posHourlySt.setDealerCode(scmsaPosTransRollup.getDealerCode());
        posHourlySt.setSourceJobLogId(scmsaPosTransRollup.getJobLogId());
        posHourlySt.setStartDate(startDate);
        posHourlySt.setStoreId(scmsaPosTransRollup.getStoreId());
        posHourlySt.setEndDate(endDate);
        posHourlySt.setJobLogId(0L);
        posHourlySt.setSource("ROLLUP");
        log.info("New Rec: {}", posHourlySt.toString());
        return posHourlySt;
    }

    public PosHourlySt createHourlyStEntryFromPosHourlySt(PosHourlySt posHourlyStToSplit, Timestamp endDate){
        PosHourlySt posHourlySt = new PosHourlySt();
        posHourlySt.setDealerCode(posHourlyStToSplit.getDealerCode());
        posHourlySt.setSourceJobLogId(posHourlyStToSplit.getJobLogId());
        posHourlySt.setStartDate(posHourlyStToSplit.getStartDate());
        posHourlySt.setStoreId(posHourlyStToSplit.getStoreId());
        posHourlySt.setEndDate(endDate);
        posHourlySt.setJobLogId(0L);
        posHourlySt.setSource("ROLLUP");
        log.info("SplitupRec: {}", posHourlySt.toString());
        return posHourlySt;
    }


    public List<ScmsaPosTransRollup> createUpdatedRollUpEntries(List<ScmsaPosTransRollup> rollUpFeedByDealerCode) {
        List<ScmsaPosTransRollup> scmsaPosTransRollupUpdatedFlagList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(ScmsaPosTransRollup scmsaPosTransRollupFeed : rollUpFeedByDealerCode) {
            ScmsaPosTransRollup scmsaPosTransRollupUpdateFlag = new ScmsaPosTransRollup();
            modelMapper.map(scmsaPosTransRollupFeed, scmsaPosTransRollupUpdateFlag);
            scmsaPosTransRollupUpdateFlag.setProcessedFlag("Y");

            scmsaPosTransRollupUpdatedFlagList.add(scmsaPosTransRollupUpdateFlag);
        }
        return scmsaPosTransRollupUpdatedFlagList;
    }
}
```

The StoreIdAssignmentService class contains the method "calculateStateForPosHourlyStTransaction" which calls some method in Factory class. When I debug as the junit test case , am not able to call that factory class method . What I am doing wrong here. Can anyone please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking the factory:

```
@Mock
private StoreIdAssignmentFactory storeIdAssignmentFactory;
```

So you can't investigate the method `createHourlyStEntryFromRollUp` inside the factory, because the whole factory is mocked:

```
storeIdAssignmentFactory.createHourlyStEntryFromRollUp
```

If you trying to debug the `createHourlyStEntryFromRollUp` and the `StoreIdAssignmentFactory` is a `@Component` (or `@Service`), I recommend create a `StoreIdAssignmentFactoryTest` class test, use the `@Autowired` on it and `@MockBean` his dependencies.

Example:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class StoreIdAssignmentFactoryTest {

    @Autowired
    StoreIdAssignmentFactory factory;

    @Test
    public void testing() {
         List<ScmsaPosTransRollup> list = factory.createHourlyStEntryFromRollUp(...);
         //TODO asserts and etc
    }

}
```

But this test is considered a **integration test,** because it load the whole spring context and beans related.

Another alternative is the (true) **unit test**. Use your constructor and not use `@SpringBootTest`, mock the dependencies (ModelMapper). This makes the test more fast and simple.

Example:

```
public class StoreIdAssignmentFactoryTest {

    @Test
    public void testing() {
         ModelMapper mapper = mock(ModelMapper.class);
         StoreIdAssignmentFactory factory = new StoreIdAssignmentFactory(mapper)
         List<ScmsaPosTransRollup> list = factory.createHourlyStEntryFromRollUp();
         //TODO asserts and etc
    }

}
```

Comment: So what else I can do

Comment: @kaviya.P, I edited my answer providing an alternative

Comment: @kaviya.P if you have more doubts about how to do, share the code of your StoreIdAssignmentFactory on the question, so I can provide a full example.

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Thanks for your response.I already have the seperate test class for factory class, Now I need to have the seperate one for service class. When I am writing the test class for the service it's failed because that function is not called so the value is null. That's my issue

Comment: @kaviya.P, I think it's better create a new question with all details of your new problem.